# SQLAlchemy Core: How can I use bindparam for LIMIT/OFFSET clause?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is the code snippet I attempted

```
query = tbl_scores.select().limit( bindparam('lim') )
```

However, I got the following error.

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'BindParameter'
```

Can anybody present an example of using bindparam for LIMIT/OFFSET?

Python 2.7.5, SQLAlchemy 0.8.4

---

Assume an webapi to return top players and their ranks. Construct an query with the bind parameter like this, then store it in a thread local place so that requests can share the same precompiled query.

```
# TypeError occurs here
a_thread_local_place.query = join(tbl_scores,
                          tbl_master_player,
                          tbl_scores.c.uid == tbl_master_player
                     ).\
                     select().limit(bindparam('lim'))
```

Everytime the webapi handles a request, I would like to execute the query like this using the precompiled query.

```
result = engine.connect().execute(
    a_thread_local_place.query,
    lim = 10,
)
```

Comment: Try like this
`query = tbl_scores.select().limit(10)`. [Refer Here](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/tutorial.html#ordering-grouping-limiting-offset-ing)

Comment: Thanks Syed, I know that query works fine. However I wanted to make it bindparam'd for the performance reason, because my actual query is more complicated with many joined tables.

Comment: Can you show us how did you execute that query? Like sample execution code.

Comment: OK Syed. I edited the question.

Comment: Did you notice one thing? `bindparam` retutns `<object BindParameter>`. But `limit` exactly wants `type str` or `type int`. Can you change `bindparam` object to `str` or `int`.  That could be fix your issue.

Comment: Yes I do notice it. I wanted to know if there is any workaround, or else bindparam for LIMIT/OFFSET is not supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you cannot, but there's an open issue for this and a patch is in progess:

https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3034/use-my-own-bindparam-for-querylimit